# Detect if a TextChanged event wasn't triggered programmatically

Tags: winforms

I have a `TextChanged` event attached to a TextBox in a Windows Form. How to make sure if a particular  call to that event wasn't triggered programmatically rather by user interacting with the TextBox?

Comment: You could use the [`KeyPress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress) event instead. That's if you want to check if the change was **Not** made programmatically (because your title says the opposite!).

Comment: Seems like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Are you trying to stop an event handler from firing when you programmatically update a `TextBox`? Is that basically what you want?

Comment: I don't think we need to worry about the root cause. Case is clear. So, should the answer be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to extend @rw_'s solution a little. Inside your `TextBox` event handler,

```
private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
             if (!(sender is null) &&((TextBox)sender).ContainsFocus)
                {
                    //Code if triggered by Click event
                }
                else
                {
                    //Code if triggered programmatically
                }
}
```

This will help your program adjust to the case where `sender` object is not null for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure about what your question means. I'll split my answer.

1. If you want to call the text changed function programmatically and differ when it was called by user interactivity or if it was called programmatically:

   Assuming that when you call the function programmatically you pass null on sender and event args

   ```
   txt_TextChanged(null,null);
   ```

   , you could use this solution:

   ```
   private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if(sender == null)
       {
           // triggered programmatically
       }
       else
       {
          // triggered by the user. sender object is the textbox interacted by the user
       } 
   }
   ```
2. If you want to change the text programmatically without triggering the event:

   ```
   this.txt.TextChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.txt_TextChanged);
   txt.Text = "bar";
   this.txt.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txt_TextChanged);
   ```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: When the method is called by the user, the sender object is the textbox object. Don't you think that this answer resolves the problem? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think the OP is calling `txt.Text = "Foo";` and he doesn't want the event firing, but when someone types in the field he does want it firing.

Comment: Improved again based on your comment. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem.  You can set a flag on your form before updating the value and then check it in your event handler:

```
handleEvent = false;
TextBox1.Text = "foo";
handleEvent = true;
```

Then in your handler, check the flag:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(handleEvent)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```